# How to show flutter description in permission handler

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions, camera

I want to make flutter permission handler look like in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEYcU5GtTUs

I already follow step by step, but in mine it does not show the description

it should be look like

[image]

but mine is look like

[image]

I already set the desciption in info.plist

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>camera for taking photos</string>
```

my code for check permission

```
Future<void> checkPermission() async {
  Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
    Permission.camera,
    Permission.location,
    Permission.storage,
    Permission.manageExternalStorage,
  ].request();
}
```

anyone how to show the description "camera for taking photos" ?

Comment: run flutter clean and then run project.

Comment: still same for me

Comment: have you added NScamera description in info.plist file?